# how to make keyboard in front of the expand whidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I built a login page which has a stock widget with two expand children 
the first expansion has the username, password text fields and login button the second expand has the signup and forget password buttons 
what happened is that when the keyboard opens the second expand appears above the keyboard and the text fields not all showing in the screen

```
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child:   Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child:  ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: spaces,
                  ),
                  loginImage,
                  SizedBox(
                    height: spaces,
                  ),
                  buildUsernameTextField(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: spaces,
                  ),
                  buildPasswordTextField(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: spaces,
                  ),
                  login(),
                ],
              ),
              ),

            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      new BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black45,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, -6.0),
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(55),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(55)),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          const Color(0xFFFF215490),
                          const Color(0xFFFF010431)
                        ],
                        tileMode: TileMode.clamp)),
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: spaces,
                    ),
                    signup(),
                    forgetPassword(),
                    //_buildPasswordTextField(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ),

    );
```

[image]

[image]

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you haven't:

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
),
```

I've just tried it and it's working as expected, I can't image why is it freezing your screen

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping but it freezes the screen so I can't enter the password

Comment: yes, because you don't have an image that takes a space from a screen if you add an image the password field will not be shown anymore

Comment: Welp, you're right, then the problem here is that you don't have space enough. You should re-scale your widgets or put some SizedBox at the end of the Form List View so you can scroll down to the password field ^^"
Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: no, you helped me a lot I fix the pic size and use your solution and everything is good, thank you!!!